# Modify array of objects into new array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like how to convert the object to array of objects in JavaScript.
In object `obj`, fields should be modified to nested array of objects in JavaScript.

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  fields: {
    color: "white",
    brand: "xyz"
  }
}]

function objarray(obj) {
  return obj.map(e => ({
    label: Object.keys(e.fields)
  }))
}

var result = objarray(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Expected Output:

```
  [
    {
      label: "color",
      children: [{label:"white" }]
    },
    {
      label: "brand",
      children: [{label:"xyz" }]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Will `obj` always be an array with one object only? If not, what would be the expected result if there are more entries in `obj`?

Comment: You're losing data in this transformation (the `id: 1`). That could be fine, but just a warning that this will be a one-way transformation.

Comment: Do you want to modify the actual object or need the array only?

Answer (score 0):

Obj.map isn't going to work as obj is an array with one element so it will only iterate one time.

```
let newArray = []
for (var i in obj.fields)
{
    newArray.push({label: i, children:obj[[0].fields.i});
}
```

I doubt this will compile. I suspect i is an object here and can't be used as a reference on obj[0].fields.

but You get the idea.

Comment: You should probably wait until [a comment asking about what happens if `obj` has more than one object in it is resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024878/modify-array-object-into-new-array-object-in-javascript#comment109700876_62024878) before answering. You should also learn about bracket syntax so that your answer "compiles" (`obj.fields[i]`).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  fields: {
    color: "white",
    brand: "xyz"
  }
}]

const mapFields = (obj) => {
  return obj.map((o) => {
    return Object.keys(o.fields).map((f) => {
      var field = {
        label: f,
        children: [{label: o.fields[f]}]
      };
      return field;
    });
  })
}

console.log(mapFields(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of `Object.entries()`:

```js
var obj = [ { id: 1, fields: { color: "white", brand: "xyz" } }];

result = Object.entries(obj[0].fields).map(([k,v])=>({label:k, children:[{label:v}]}))

console.log(result)
```